# wp_localize_script returns underfined in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to pass a WordPress shortcode attribute to jQuery as a variable, but it keeps returning as `undefined` in jQuery. Everything with the shortcode function works as intended, same for the jQuery aside from the attribute returning as `undefined`. The jQuery script is also enqueuing properly.

This is the start of my PHP function:

```
function aw_simple_sorter_creator($atts) {

extract(shortcode_atts(array(   
    'show_posts' => '-1',
    'effect' => ''
), $atts, 'aw_simple_sorter' ));

wp_enqueue_script('aw_simple_sorter_js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/aw_simple_sorter.js');
wp_localize_script('aw_simple_sorter_js', 'aw_ss_script_vars', array(
        'jQueryUIeffect' => __($effect),
    )
);
```

In the above snippet, `$effect` should be equal to the shortcode attribute. The shortcode attribute does have a value as well. I've also tried `'jQueryUIeffect' => $effect,` instead of this `'jQueryUIeffect' => __($effect),`, but it still returns `undefined` in jQuery.

Then in my jQuery I'm trying to test the passed variable using the following wrapped in a `.ready()`:

`alert(aw_ss_script_vars.jQueryUIeffct);`

Am I going about this the wrong way? Does something jump out that looks incorrect? Thanks.

Comment: Anyone have any input on this?

Comment: What do you see if you do a view source of the page, and search for `jQueryUIeffect`?  It is being initialised correctly?  ie can you narrow down the problem as to whether it's client side or server side?

Comment: Your alert has a typo by the way - it should be `alert(aw_ss_script_vars.jQueryUIeffect);`.  I assume you haven't been using the incorrect string in your jQuery code?

Comment: I have this in the source: `<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var aw_ss_script_vars = {"jQueryUIeffect":"testing"};
/* ]]> */
</script>` so the variable seems to be set correctly, but when I try to use it in jQuery is returns `undefined`.

Comment: Simple as that, it was the typo. Sometimes it just takes an extra set of eyes! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should start by changing your enqueue for register, secondly pass in the jquery dependancy.

If the script is being output on the page as you mention in the comments above, then the problem is likely in how you're trying to access the variables.

```
function do_scripts()
{   

    /* register the script */
    wp_register_script( 'custom', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )  . '/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'), false, true );
    $script_vars = array(
        'key' => $value
        ... your values here....
    );

    /* actually enqueue jquery (that ships with WP) and your custom script */
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom' );

    /* Localize the vairables */
    wp_localize_script('custom', 'script_vars', $script_vars);

}

/* If we're not in the admin section call our function on the wp_enqueue_scripts hook  */
if ( !is_admin() ) add_action( "wp_enqueue_scripts", "do_scripts", 10 );
```

to see if the variables are available, open your console in google chrome developer tools and type `script_vars`

in your script you should be able to access your values with dot notation as follows :

```
script_vars.yourKey
```